# ES+Shield+Kibana : Authorization on document level

Tags: kibana-4

In 'kibana' we can restrict specific user to access specific indices. e.g. user 'A'  can access only 'logs-*' indices.

I want to know the way how to implement such access for document level instead of indices level.

I searched lot but I did not get any solution for document level authorization. Could you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it works but you can just give a try. In roles.yml, create a different roles specific to document level authorization. For example,

```
roleA:
'.kibana': 
    indices: 'indexA'
    privileges: read
    fields: 
      - fieldA
      - fieldB
```

in the rolemapping.yml, map the authenticated user to this respective role. Then only the selected fields will be applicable to Kibana from the elastic search.

Try out this option.

Answer (score 0):

in elasticsearch container

```
usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/shield ./esusers useradd user1 -p userpass -r rolename
```

after that

add role in /etc/elasticsearch/shield/roles.yml

```
rolename:
  cluster: 
      - cluster:monitor/nodes/info
      - cluster:monitor/health 
  indices:
    'logs*':
      privileges: indices:admin/mappings/fields/get, indices:admin/validate/query, indices:data/read/search, indices:data/read/msearch, indices:data/read/field_stats, indices:admin/get
    '.kibana':
      privileges: indices:admin/exists, indices:admin/mapping/put, indices:admin/mappings/fields/get, indices:admin/refresh, indices:admin/validate/query, indices:data/read/get, indices:data/read/mget, indices:data/read/search, indices:data/write/delete, indices:data/write/index, indices:data/write/update
```